# Should I split my edmx or not?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, unit-of-work

I am working on an application I want to install in different businesses. Each business might need different parts of this application. For example, the application have the following modules: Company management, Tasks management and Bookkeeping management. One business would like me to install him only the Company management and Bookkeeping management modules where other would like to install all the three modules.

Those modules (I have more than 3) are sitting in one data base (historical reason) and I prefer not to separate the data base. Moreover, there is a dependency - each module should know the Company management models since it has all the lists of customers, workers suppliers and more. Except this, each module can considered as a separate application.

The application was written in C# .Net and I am using the entity framework. Here is the list of projects in my solution:

1. Data folder

   - **MyApp.Data.EF4**: Contains the edmx and implementation of the unit of work and repository patterns. I am using POCOs so the edmx doesn't create the entities. Contains reference only to MyApp.Common.
2. Modules folder

   - Common folder

     - **MyApp.Common**: Contains all the interfaces for the MyApp.Data.EF4 project to implement.
     - **MyApp.Company.Domain**: Contains the domain objects (POCOs) for the Company module. This project has no reference to any of the projects.
     - **MyApp.Company.Services.Contract**: Contains the interface of the services this module expose.
     - **MyApp.Company.Services**: Contains the services implementation.
   - Tasks folder

     - **MyApp.Tasks.Domain**: Contains the domain objects (POCOs) for the Tasks module. This project has reference only to MyApp.Company.Domain.
     - **MyApp.Tasks.Services.Contract**: Contains the interface of the services this module expose.
     - **MyApp.Tasks.Services**: Contains the services implementation.
   - Bookkeeping folder

     - **MyApp.Bookkeeping.Domain**: Contains the domain objects (POCOs) for the Bookkeeping module. This project has reference only to MyApp.Company.Domain.
     - **MyApp.Bookkeeping.Services.Contract**: Contains the interface of the services this module expose.
     - **MyApp.Tasks.Services**: Contains the services implementation.
3. Presentation folder

   - **MyApp.Web**: Web application that has references to all the other modules Service, Contract and Domain. This specific web app should cover presentation for all my modules. Which means, only businesses with the need of all the modules will get this web app.

Because I have really large edmx, what makes it really difficult to manage, I thought about splitting the edmx so that each module will have its own edmx. This will cause MyApp.Web project to hold unit of work for each module (because the MyApp.Web uses all the modules and therefore need all the units of work).

I am thinking whether splitting the edmx into different edmxs is a good practice for me. I would appriciate any explanation that will help me to decide if this is a good idea or not, or any good workaround to my case.

Comment: I don't think splitting it into multiple edmx files would wive you any performance advantage. The only advantage I see here is easy management.

Comment: @Afshin Gh: Does it hurt performance so bad? I cannot manage a lot of thables in one edmx. It is impossible.

Comment: :I have no idea if it will affect performance or not. I think the only advantage of multiple EDMX files is easy management, however in my own project i normally generate EDMX from db  and that's it. EDMX is not touched as long as there is no change in DB.

Comment: @Afshin Gh: I have to make changes in my edmx since the tables names and the columns names are not the same as my entities. I also use inheritance and other features that should be configured in the edmx. Doing this for all my tables is very difficult, the computer acts slow and it is very hard to modify and read the data.

Answer (score 0):

I work with multiple emdx files it is a good idea. It keeps parts of the system separate, which is a good thing.

There will be, however, a chunk of your database which is accessed from multiple edmx files. It just ends up like this :) In this case be aware that if you change the database then you may have to update these multiple edmx files. It is not a blocker, just a thing to be aware of.

Having said that, what about:
a) buying more memory ([Hardware is Cheap, Programmers are Expensive](http://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html)
b) 'freezing' the old edmx and putting new tables into the new emdx and only doing incremental changes

On a more general level, if you don't split your edmx one day your replacement will ask a question on StackOverflow which will contain the following line: "Those modules (I have more then 3) are sitting in one data model (edmx) (historical reason) and I prefer not to saperate the edmx." ;)